# XGBoost model with real time data

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost, algorithmic-trading

I need a clarification about my FOREX machine learning strategy cause I'm a little bit confused.

I train/test and save an XGBoost classification model in a pickle file.

Then in my broker's algo trading loop I import that model and try to predict real time data (historical data until today in a loop that updates last candle) opening a buy/sell order depending on a forecast class

Unfortunately I get this error:

```
ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 41 and input n_features is 1
```

Why? I really have to pre-process live data like my train/test dataframe? I just thought that saving and importing pickled models would help to avoid this step inside a live brokerage streaming.

I know, logically, that a boosted tree is a set of rules built upon data features, so it is illogical to think that those rules could be applied to a single row of returns. But...

Last question: every update on real time data my algo takes last two rows, calculates return and assigns a classification label (1, -1) based on returns sign (if return >0, 1, -1). What should be my predict target, return or binary label?

For example:

```
my_model.predict(?)[0]
```

What do I put in the parenthesis here?

Comment: "*I really have to preprocess live data like my train/test dataframe?*" Well, yes...?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro & **NOTE** in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Comment: I guess your call to the **`.predict()`**-method just successfully ignored the actual *`<input_DATA>.shape`*. Review it & repair the call to match the XGB-model ( **`<input_DATA>[0]`** being the first candidate, `<input_DATA>[0,:]` being a next, if some smart vectorised trading tricks were designed in. :o) try the *`.shape`* first to see what you actually tried to cast onto the XGB (expecting nothing else but a vector of [n:n+41] input-features or a matrix of [n:n+41,m:m+rows] rows of input-features ). + Happy trading !

Comment: In your previous question here, you were already [advised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64864969/machine-learning-model-forecasting-on-real-time-data#comment114682485_64864969) that, yes, you need to apply all the preprocessing steps to the real data as well. Repeating the same question is indeed not helpful for anyone.

Comment: You're right, but in my previous question i just asked about reshape. Now i'm asking about the entire preprocessing repeating